# How to setup Vuetify 3 for Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I followed this guide https://codybontecou.com/how-to-use-vuetify-with-nuxt-3.html without the *Customize Sass Variables* section. I installed the packages

- vuetify
- sass
- @mdi/font

Inside the plugins directory the vuetify.ts contains

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        ssr: true,
        components,
        directives,
    })

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

and the nuxt.config.ts contains

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify']
    }
});
```

I tried the setup with the following code in app.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { VApp, VAppBar, VMain, VBtn } from "vuetify/components";
</script>

<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-app-bar title="App bar goes here"></v-app-bar>

        <v-main>
            <v-btn color="primary" prepend-icon="mdi-vuetify">Main content goes here</v-btn>

            <v-btn prepend-icon="mdi-check-circle" append-icon="mdi-account-circle">
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <v-icon color="success"></v-icon>
                </template>

                Button

                <template v-slot:append>
                    <v-icon color="warning"></v-icon>
                </template>
            </v-btn>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

I get the following result

[image]

I think I'm missing something because the font looks too small, the button should have a font similiar to

[image]

I tried to manipulate the style and I think my buttons are missing a font-weight of 600. So my app might not import some css classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing font (Roboto) is typically loaded in using a webfont loader lib but in Nuxt I think you can just add the font in `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'preconnect',
          href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com'
        },
        {
          rel: 'preconnect',
          href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
          crossorigin: ''
        },
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```